# How to load URL from assets

Tags: angular, typescript, assets

I am trying to define a baseUrl for my backend requests in the assets folder.

I wrote the server to a json file
called: config.json

```
{
  "backendServer": {
    "protocol": "http",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": "3001"
  }
}
```

I then made an app.config.ts file with the load() function

```
  load() {
    const jsonFile = `./../assets/config.json`;
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http
        .get(jsonFile)
        .toPromise()
        .then((response: IAppConfig) => {
          AppConfig.settings = response as IAppConfig;
          this.setDefaultValues();
          resolve();
        })
        .catch((response: any) => {
          reject(`Could not load file '${jsonFile}': ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
        });
    });
  }
```

AppConfig is a model which I store in a models folder:

```
export interface IAppConfig {
  backendServer: {
    protocol: string;
    host: string;
    port: string;
  };}
```

In app.modules.ts the initalization is triggerd

```
export function initializeApp(appConfig: AppConfig) {
  return () => appConfig.load();
}
```

In the providersArray I use
AppConfig,
{ provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initializeApp, deps: [AppConfig], multi: true },

I then try in a backend.service.ts to get the Url with the method:

```
getUrlPrefix() {
    return `${AppConfig.settings.backendServer.protocol}://${AppConfig.settings.backendServer.host}:${AppConfig.settings.backendServer.port}`;
  }
```

I hostet the local http-server when I call the website there ist following error in the console:

ERROR Could not load file './../assets/config.json': {}
I've seen the other questions about that topic but the suggestion is always to but it in env. Thats not an option due to requirements.
Is there any option to make it work with assets?

Comment: why not use  const jsonfile="assets/config.json"

Comment: I also tried that version but the error still appears

Comment: I also want to point out here that I load images from the assets folder and that does work. So therefor the angular.json configuration must work.

Answer (score 0):

Your path should always be realtive to your domain.

You try to load from `./../assets/config.json`

The right path should be `./assets/config.json`

You cant't move a directory upwards here because you have to think of a domains perspective. When you dont built your app with `--base-href` your domain always looks like this: `http://localhost:3000/assets/config.json` If you wold use a `--base-href=myapp` it would looks like this: `http://localhost:3000/myapp/assets/config.json`

Comment: Very good suggestion my path does indeed not make any sense. Unfortunately the error still appears after I changed the path

Comment: Take a look at the angular.json if it recognizes your assets correctly